# MySQL table query для создания col с row

Tags: mysql, sql

Доброго времени суток! 
Помогите пожалуйста столбец region из row перенести в col (поместить в него значение forecast и region со значением quantity) при этом учитывая что регионов может быть любое кол-во, буду очень благодарен за полезные статьи. Если не сложно прокомментируйте, так как у меня пока что еще ничего не получается.

Запрос:

```
SELECT products.name product,
       products.price,
       regions.region,
       SUM(forecasts.quantity) AS quantity,
       SUM(forecasts.forecast) AS forecast,
       forecasts.start_date
FROM forecasts
     LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = forecasts.product_id
     LEFT JOIN regions ON regions.id = forecasts.region_id
WHERE forecasts.start_date = "2016-11-14"
GROUP BY forecasts.product_id,
         forecasts.region_id;
```

Вот таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После, полученные данные выводим в вот такую таблицу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Вы хотите там, где quantity != 0 в ячейке region была записана конкатенация region+forecast+quantity? или что? сделать update или select? ..........`столбец region из row перенести в col (поместить в него значение forecast и region со значением quantity)` - это непонятно

Comment: SQL pivot. Я сам front-end и мне пришлось писать проект в целом, это последняя часть моего приложения. Нужна помощь с запросом который динамически будет добавлять по 2 столбца на 1 регион (первый это region quantity, второй region forecast) и соответственно подставит значения quantity и forecast которые соответствуют товару и региону. Как-то вот так. Пока что у меня не получается выполнить..

В пример |Dnepr forecast | Dnepr quantity| USA forecast| USA quantity| и тд в зависимости от количества зарегистрированных регионов. Большое спасибо за то что откликнулись!

Comment: |product|price|Dnepr forecast|Dnepr quantity|USA forecast|USA quantity|n quantity|n forecst|date|  
В итоге должна получиться таблица вот такого вида с учетом того что регионов может быть  n

Comment: Ясно. Понятно. Не смотря на такую задачу, просто хочу заметить, что такой подход неверен. Тем более если регионов может быть десятки. Вам самому будет удобно с распухшей таблицей на сотню столбцов?........... Общая сумма по региону всегда спокойно выбирается запросом и отдается опрошающему в любой момент из подобной таблицы.. Для этого не надо лепить такие костыли. Но если вы думаете, что это повысит так производительность и сильно хочется, то уж как минимум надо завести отдельную таблицу с колонками `id/region/total_forecast/total_quantity` и апдейтить таблицу раз в N-ное время.

Comment: Эта таблица собрана по средствам SELECT и JOIN, мне собственно нужно собрать запрос чтоб развернуть ее в нужное направление, забрать данные отправить на клиент и забыть)
По количеству столбцов я подразумеваю количество до 30 штук, товаров 30. На каждый товар люди делают прогноз и мы его фильтруем по регионам, региону, seller, customer, company..
Если у вас есть лучшее решение давайте обсудим, вдруг действительно заработался и не в ту степь пошел.. Критика это хорошо

Comment: Изначально для каждого customer(a), seller делает прогноз разбитый на периоды (неделя, 2 недели, 3,4, 2 месяца и так  4 мес). Запрос что я написал он получает данные за период времени и суммирует под регион, seller, company, customer. Посмотрите прикрепленный скриншот таблицы.

Comment: Это невозможно. Количество выводимых столбцов жестко фиксируется в самом SQL-запросе. динамически столбцы не добавляются. Т.е. если вам надо до 30 столбцов то вам придется явно в запросе описать все 30 и при этом прямо в тексте задавать конкретные регионы для них. Гораздо проще такое преобразование выполнить на клиенте

Comment: Mike , посоветуйте в какую сторону смотреть, а то у меня уже за сутки взгляд очень сильно замылен